# pGetText in haskell

Tags: haskell, gettext, ffi

For a lot of very short translatable strings it is useful to provide a context to the translator. However, hgettext doesn't seem to export/define the `pgettext` function.

Is there another way to deal with such shorts translatable strings in haskell or is it just (yet) not implemented in haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own ffi binding in the [same manner of](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgettext-0.1.30/docs/src/Text-I18N-GetText.html#getText) the others. Its not hard!

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "libintl.h pgettext" c_pgettext
    :: CString -> CString -> IO CString

pGetText :: String    
         -> String             
         -> IO String  
pGetText msgctxt msgid = 
    withCString msgctxt $ \ctxt' ->
        withCString msgid $ \msg' ->
            c_pgettext ctxt' msg' >>= fromCStringDefault msgid
```